# Há um termo para hortifrútis em Portugal?

Tags: vocabulário

Em Brasil, o termo hortifrúti significa "local em que são comercializados os produtos provenientes de hortas, geralmente, frutas, legumes, hortaliças etc.". Há semelhante termo em Portugal? Ou então, é essa palavra também usada em Portugal?

Comment: Que pena que quitanda não serve. Se você olhar no Priberam, a palavra não se encontra.

Comment: [Quitanda está no priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/quitanda), mas eu não reconheço a palavra. Pessoas de 50 ou mais anos talvez a conheçam, por causa das influências culturais das ex-colónias, mas mais novos que isso talvez não.

Comment: @ANeves A palavra quitanda é super conhecida **no Brasil**. Nada a ver com idade ou ex-colónias.

Comment: Pois. Como a pergunta é sobre "**em Portugal**", eu achei que era útil dar a visão euro-portuguesa sobre palavra quitanda.

Comment: O termo "_horitfrútis_", para mim (falante nativo de PT-BR do Sul) significa os alimentos em si e não o local onde eles são vendidos! Me soaria Ok ouvir "Vou no súper comprar _hortifrútis_", mas bem estranho dizer: "Vou no _hortifrúti_ comprar milho". Poderia esclarecer (ou limitar) onde no BR que _horitfrúti_ corresponde ao local?

Comment: Consegui achar locais que vendem hortaliças com hortifrúti no nome em todos os estados do sul do Brasil. Não acho que seja estranho a todos os sulinos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, a palavra "hortifrútis" não é usada em Portugal.
Percebe-se bem o que é, mas acho que nunca a tinha ouvido antes.

Em Portugal, chama-se a isso uma **frutaria**.
O foco é mais em fruta, mas vende quase sempre também bastantes legumes.

---

Por exemplo, a Frutaria de Campanhã no Porto [vende legumes](https://www.instagram.com/p/CKlZggXFXni):

> Todos os dias recebemos os nossos legumes da Póvoa , para que os mesmos cheguem a sua casa fresquinhos

A Frutaria Doce Maçã, em Lisboa, não só vende muitos legumes como [o próprio papel de parede inclui imensos](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=815131239404404&set=pcb.815131262737735):

[image: foto mostrando muitos legumes à venda e um papel de parede com todo o tipo de legumes e fruta]

O Mercadito da Fruta, em Coimbra, que tem o site em manutenção, [mostra uma imagem que só tem legumes, e de fruta nada](https://mercaditodafruta.pt/).

[image: captura de ecrã do site do Mercadito da Fruta, mostrando imensos legumes]

Comment: Apenas um comentário à parte: na última foto há raízes, legumes e verduras.

Comment: Frutaria, que nome simples, não pensei nisso. Nem o sinonimos.com.br o sugeriu.

Comment: Se é para ser preciosista, na última foto há simplesmente hortaliças e feijão-verde - que não é tecnicamente hortaliça por ser uma leguminosa. :) Em linguagem corrente portuguesa, diz-se que há nessa foto legumes; veja-se por exemplo a categoria "[frutas e legumes](https://www.continente.pt/frutas-e-legumes)" da loja online do Continente.

Comment: E por coincidência hoje falei de leguminosas (e.g. feijão-verde), e acho que o que aprendi é interessante para este contexto: botanicamente, as [Leguminosae](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabaceae) (ou Fabaceae) são uma família gigantesca com 19 mil espécies, desde os feijões às acácias...